# rerender after fetch POST and PUT request

Tags: reactjs

I have an app that GET's data from a REST API. I am able to fetch the data. I also need to be able to POST data to the API and PUT edits to the API. My code is able to successfully perform all of these operations, however I need to refresh the page to see the submissions. The trouble I am having is with automatically rerender the page upon submissions. I know I either have to setState or refetch the API after the call. I do not know how to structure this though. Any suggestions?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

 class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: [],
      isLoaded: false,
    }
    this.editBeersLikes = this.editBeersLikes.bind(this);
    this.addNewBeer = this.addNewBeer.bind(this);
  }

   seeBeers() {
   return fetch("https://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer/")//specify id number to show single beer ex. "https://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer/99"
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(responseJson => {
       this.setState({
         isLoaded: true,
         dataSource: responseJson,
       });
       return responseJson;
     })
     .catch(error => console.log(error)); //to catch the errors if any
 }

   addNewBeer() {
    fetch("https://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer/", {
      body: "{\"name\":\"\",\"likes\":\"\"}",//input beer name and like amount ex "{\"name\":\"Michelob Ultra\",\"likes\":\"-5\"}"
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      method: "POST"
      })
      console.log("Beer Added!");
  }

   editBeersLikes() {
    fetch("https://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer/99", {//must specify id number to edit a single beer's likes ex "https://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer/99"
          body: "{\"likes\":\"\"}", //input amount of likes to edit ex "{\"likes\":\"22\"}"
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
          },
          method: "PUT"
          })
          console.log("Likes Successfully Updated!");
        }

         componentDidMount() {
          this.seeBeers();
          //this.editBeersLikes(); //uncomment when you want to edit likes
          //this.addNewBeer();  //uncomment when you want to add beers
        }


   render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <h1>What is in My Fridge?</h1>

         <ul>
          {this.state.dataSource.map(dataSource => {
            return <li key={`dataSource-${dataSource.id}`}>{dataSource.name} | {dataSource.likes}</li>
          })}
        </ul>

       </div>
    );
  }
}

 export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to re-fetch the data after you have successfully POSTed or PUT them to the server. That would also be the cleanest and least error prone way because you always get a fresh response from the server with the most recent set of data.

However, you could use a pattern that is often referred to as "optimistic ui", meaning that you keep two states: the current state and the state how it will look like *if* the server request is successful. You would then push the new or updated item to your `dataSource` state and show it in your UI but revert it to the old state from before the server request if the request fails.

The downside of the latter approach is that you sometimes don't know all the data (especially auto generated IDs or `lastUpdated` fields) without querying the server again.

So if you want a relatively easy, clear, and solid solution you can call `this.seeBeers()` after each POST/PUT request to receive an updated set of data.

Keep in mind that this might not always work as expected when you're using e.g. sharding or an elastic search layer for read operations as they might not be in sync directly after you finished the write operation. That's probably not relevant for you though, as that's usually only a challenge when working with large scale setups.

Comment: YESSSSSS!!! Thank you so much. The this.seeBeers(); function worked perfectly!! One more thing: in my componentWillMount method, I am having to comment out this.editBeersLIkes and this.addNewBeers. Is there a more appropriate way of preventing these from executing? –

Comment: Why do you need them in `componentDidMount` at all? In a typical application you would call them after a user interacts with your UI, e.g. by filling a form to add new beers or pressing some sort of "like" button to add a like. The `componentDidMount` method is usually used to fetch data, register timers or events, etc. Using it to initiate write operations (like POST or PUT) would be rather unusual.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thank you for your assistance with this issue.